# What is the alternative to kill/clear text till the end of buffer?

Tags: emacs

Is their an alternative to <kbd>C-Spc</kbd><kbd>M-></kbd><kbd>del</kbd>/<kbd>backspace</kbd> for killing text, possibly just deleting without polluting and bloating the kill-ring, up till the end of the buffer?

Asking because I don't find the method, stated above, quite elegant.

**Edit:**

[wvxvw's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669287/what-is-the-alternative-to-kill-clear-text-till-the-end-of-buffer#comment25737302_17669287) was a good one but I discovered that it won't work on extremely large files because Emacs doesn't allow stacking of more than *fourteen* <kbd>C-u</kbd>.

Comment: How about `C-u C-u C-u C-u C-k` - that's what I normally do :D On a more serious note - I don't think there's a built-in, but writing a function for it would be really simple.

Comment: See http://emacs-journey.blogspot.in/2012/09/vim-influences-prefixes-and-deleting-to.html for an option!

Comment: @wvxvw not a bad idea :) easily adding a few more `C-u`s would conquer extremely large(10^6+ lines) files too. But the bloating/pollution of the kill-ring is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>M-></kbd> sets the mark before jumping to the end of the buffer, so just <kbd>M-> M-x delete-region</kbd> will do it.  You could bind a key to the latter if you do it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that ELISP function in your .emacs

```
(defun bruce-kill-to-end ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (point))
        (end (point-max)))
    (delete-region beg end)))
```

Then bind it to whatever you like:

```
(global-set-key [f9] 'bruce-kill-to-end)
```

**EDIT**
If you have a selection, it does not start from current cursor but from begin of selection

**EDIT 2** : removed part about selection

Comment: This will not work as expected. `(mark)` returns the previous mark even when the region isn't active (i.e. when there's no selection). You'll probably end up killing a lot more then you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
(defun delete-to-end-of-buffer (add-to-kill-ring-p)
  "Deletes from point to end of buffer.
   If prefix argument is given, kill the region, adding it to the kill ring."
  (interactive "P")
  (if add-to-kill-ring-p
      (kill-region (point) (point-max))
    (delete-region (point) (point-max))))
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://echosa.github.io/blog/2012/09/27/vim-influences-prefixes-and-deleting-to/) a while back concerning this. It is similar to Bruce's answer but gives you the option of sending a prefix argument (C-u) to the command, in which case the text will be "cut" (added to the kill ring) instead of just deleted.